# Visual Studio on an USB key?

Tags: visual-studio, usb-drive

Is this possible or does it require a local install?

Comment: Why do you need it on a USB key, don't you have your own workstation?

Comment: I do, but I want to just fool around with some code at work on my downtime. I can do it without Visual Studio but it's not as convenient. Oh, and I can't install things on work computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I would definitely have thought you would need to have it installed as it requires .NET and a fair deal of windows .dlls as well as registry keys.

Some programs have been made portable (such as Nero portable) but with Visual Studio being such a huge program I doubt you could do the same without a lot of work.